# Delete invisible directory after a git clone

Tags: git, shell, rmdir

I did a clone of ([Github mCSS-SublimeText](https://github.com/karbassi/mCSS-SublimeText)) in this repository :
`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\Pristine Packages"`

The clone was a success but I cant see it in my "Pristine Packages" folder. But when I do the command `ls`, the folder mCSS seems to be here.

Moreover this folder isn't empty. I used the `cd` command to see it.

So I tried a `rmdir /S mCSS` but the output is : `"Directory not empty"` and `"/S no such file or directory"`

Comment: I experienced the same problem cloning `git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv` in Cygwin under Win XP. It said it was cloned, but there was no any dir named `.rbenv`. Neither by `ls -a` nor by Win Explorer I checked. My solution was: `rm -rf .rbenv`, create `.rbenv` dir manually in advance and then run the clone command again. Maybe my comment will help smb as your question helped me. Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rm -rf mCSS
```

doesn't work? what do you mean by "invisible"?

Comment: Nice ! Thx a lot :)

Invisible means that I couldn't see the folder called "mCSS" in "Pristine Packages".